# Different GoogleAuthenticator Codes received on two different servers running the same code

Tags: php, sonata, google-authenticator

This is a strange problem and just looking for some ideas of where to look, or what it could possibly be, please.

On my local dev machine, XAMPP PHP 7.1, sonata Google-Authenticator v2.2
When I do $GoogleAuthenticator->getCode($secret)
I receive the same code I can see on my mobile/cell phone.

On a remote server A2Hosting, the code is not the same.

Both servers using the same code, just my local machine is http, and remote is https, with different host/domain-names.

To make this very weird is that $GoogleAuthenticator->checkCode($secret, $code) *returns true*

How is it possible that getCode compared to what I enter is not the same, while checkCode returns true?

My only idea is that the server has an issue with DateTimeImmutable
not returning the right time. Maybe the server is not sync'd with the right world time.
I did notice that DateTimeImmutable timestamp is a few seconds different to the remote server. Around 25 seconds different.

Comment: I believe you've identified the issue with regards to the time sync. If I'm not mistaken, there is a grace period where the old code is still allowed for a short period of time beyond the expiration -- this would effectively allow your two codes to work at the same time.

Comment: I'm limited to version 2.2 due to a limit of the PHP version I can use.
Should I compare the code from new version to old and make adjustments? Will this fix the issue?

Comment: If there's any issue to be fixed, I'd say it's the time sync of the remote server. 25 seconds is quite a bit to be off.

Comment: Because it apparently needs to be said multiple times, that server where you noticed that the time is off by 25 seconds? Its time is off by 25 seconds, which is causing your issue. Have your server admin re-sync the time and turn its ntpd back on.